# AngularJS load issue in asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to use angular in my asp.net mvc website .
Every thing works fine in home page (localhost:xxxx) for loading carousel, but when i redirect to admin page(localhost:xxxx/admin), i get below error on browser console

```
> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=MollahajiModule&p1=[$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=MollahajiModule
N/<@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:412
ke/</</<@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:25:99
b@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:24:142
ke/</<@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:24:385
g/<@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:471
q@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:353
g@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:319
cb@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:43:336
Bc/c@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:390
Bc@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:21:179
fe@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:1
@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/angular.min.js:317:386
jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:3062:10
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:3174:7
.ready@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:447:3
completed@http://localhost:25150/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:118:4
```

I've also tried route, but got no result

```
    var Application = angular.module('AdminModule', ["ngRoute"]);
Application.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/admin', {
            templateUrl: '/Views/Admin/Index.html',
            controller: 'HomeCarouselController'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: what is MollahajiModule angular says that can't find this module, maybe if you can fill a jsfiddle with the code it will be helpful

Comment: Usually get this when you are using incorrect value for `ng-app` Check you are using `ng-app="AdminModule"` on your admin page. And make sure you have added script on page e.g. <script src="app/modules/AdminModule.js"></script>

Comment: Another thought, ensure you have `angular-route.js` script included on the page - also if you temporarily change minified `angular.min.js` for `angular.js` you should get better error message.